# How can I add a custom domain to an AWS Amplify Gen 2 app?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I have a domain [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) that I wanna to associate with my deployed app on Apmlify Gen 2. How can I do it, since the Custom domains option is disable?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Custom domain support for Amplify Gen 2 apps is currently in development and is not available as part of the preview. That being said, as stated in this thread you can add custom domains to your Gen 2 apps using the AWS CLI/API/SDK.

To add a custom domain, you can use the create-domain-association AWS CLI:

`aws amplify create-domain-association --app-id <VALUE> --domain-name <VALUE> --sub-domain-settings prefix=<VALUE>,branchName=<VALUE>`

Ref: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-backend/issues/954
They didn't implement this feature in Gen 2 UI but provided a workaround above.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please consider adding the actual solution to your answer, instead of just posting a link.

Comment: sure, will edit